# How to adjust online grids to desktop web design and mobile web design in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, interface-design, grids

There are many good grids online (1200px.com, unsemantic.com) that can be downloaded as PSD and used in web design in Photoshop. Now I have 2 questions in relation with this:

1. When I apply this template in my Photoshop document, they have small right and left margins, how do I adjust such templates to my needs because I want MORE white space, not 5-10px as the templates have? (do I go to canvas size and increase the size of canvas on both sides or else?)
2. How to use same 12 column grid template for mobile web design?

May be I am thinking the wrong direction, I am just confused, your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

> how do I adjust such templates to my needs because I want MORE white
>   space

[Griddify](http://gelobi.org/griddify/?utm_source=designernews) is a free plugin for PS that allows you to easily compose custom grid systems with columns and white spacing.

> How to use same 12 column grid template for mobile web design?

Simply adjust the settings to fit your new screen size.

Answer (score 0):

As [Afterteam](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/61344/afterteam) wrote Griddify is a cool plugin.

You can also use:

- http://960.gs/
- http://guideguide.me/

If you have Photoshop CC go to View\New Guide Layout and choose your measurements that you  want to use :)

Your second question can be solved in two ways:

- again like Afterteam wrote :)
- set less number of columns (this same size as in desktop view) for mobile (example: Desktop: 12 column, Tablet 8 column, mobile 3 column)